# Converting string EST time to localized time

Tags: ios, swift

Assume I'm given an input string like "7:00". I know that the time is EST but I want to convert it to localized time (so for people in PST it says 4:00). I tried the following code, but I keep getting a 24-hour time from it and the complete date (e.g: Optional(2000-01-01 16:00:00 +0000)). I want just the hour:min time...what am I doing wrong?

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
gameClock = "\(dateFormatter.dateFromString("7:30"))"
println(gameClock)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the time zone for your date formatter that you use to process the server date. By default, the time zone of the date formatter is the default time zone of the device.

So, for your above code, you should do this:

```
let dateStringFromServer = "07:00"    

let serverDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
serverDateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
serverDateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "EST")

let dateFromServer = serverDateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStringFromServer)

let localDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
serverDateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

let localizedStringForThatDate = localDateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateFromServer!)
```

Comment: Never use time zone names. They are not standardized. Always create time zones using time offset.

Answer (score 0):

The `dateFormatter.dateFromString("7:30")` gives you an `NSDate` not an `NSString`. You have make use of another `NSDateFormatter` object to get the date in desired string format.

```
let dateFormatterForDisplay = NSDateFormatter();
dateFormatterForDisplay.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
dateFormatterForDisplay.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

(you need the last line in the above if you want to force 12 hour mode, the default is NSLocale.currentLocale() and can be 12 hr or 24 hr mode for different locales)

Then

```
let displayString = dateFormatterForDisplay.stringFromDate(gameClock)
```